# Magento extension not installing database tables

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, ce-1.9.2.1

I've bumped into an odd problem on my local running version of Magento 1.9.2.1. I installed the Fishpig Splash Pages plugin which was working fine, but I uninstalled it (as I was testing different plugins to see which worked best).

I then decided this extension was the best one that was going to suit my requirements so I reinstalled it. After this install, One or more of the Indexes are not up to date - meaning I had to run the Attribute Splash reindex, but when running this I received the error: `Cannot initialize the indexer process`. I then tried manually running the indexer via `\shell\indexer.php --reindex` - and this produced some PHP errors that indicate the tables don't even exist.

I then created a brand new install of Magento running 1.9.2.1 - the plugin installed fine and correctly created the splash pages database tables. What could be causing my other copy not to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include the steps taken during uninstallation, so this is only a guess: You forgot to remove the respective entry in the `core_resource` table.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `core_resource` WHERE `code` = 'attributeSplash_setup';
```

With this entry still present, the (re-)installation process skips the (re-)creation of the extension's database tables.

Comment: You hero! Thanks! I assumed the uninstallation of a plugin would have carried out such steps but I completely overlooked this!